# How to fix Cannot read property 'time' of undefined in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-7

I wanted to display available data from an api to Angular Material Datatable. The response does not always return the same content like this (see below). I'm trying to incorporate the *ngIf.

```
{
  id: "123",
  date: "2019-04-15"
  am_in: { id: "0001", time: "08:00 AM" }
},
{
  id: "456",
  date: "2019-04-16"
  am_in: { id: "0031", time: "07:00 AM" },
  am_out: { id: "0041", time: "11:24 AM" }
}
```

I've seen samples online (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9ckf8?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) and it's working fine even if I remove some data. Wondering why mine is not.

Comment: Sorry, what is wrong with your code? What are you trying to show/do on your datatable

Answer (score 0):

> ### **CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datatable-app)
>
> **This is directly forked from the link you provided and the data you are using!**

---

> I've seen samples online
>   (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9ckf8?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   and it's working fine even if I remove some data. Wondering why mine
>   is not.

**Your `component.html` can be something like below:~**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">My full table</mat-toolbar>

<mat-table #table [dataSource]="yetAnotherdataSource" matSort *ngIf="yetAnotherdataSource.length > 0">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element?.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="Date">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element?.date}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="AM IN">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Am_in </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element?.am_in?.time}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="AM OUT">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Am_out </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element?.am_out?.time}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="row.toggle(row)">
    </mat-row>
</mat-table>

<div *ngIf="yetAnotherdataSource.length === 0">No data</div>
```

**and your `component.ts` has data like you provided:~**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  name = 'Angular 5';
  displayedColumns = ['ID', 'Date', 'AM IN', 'AM OUT'];
  yetAnotherdataSource = [
    {
      id: "123",
      date: "2019-04-15",
      am_in: { id: "0001", time: "08:00 AM" }
    },
    {
      id: "456",
      date: "2019-04-16",
      am_in: { id: "0031", time: "07:00 AM" },
      am_out: { id: "0041", time: "11:24 AM" }
    }
  ];
}
```

**Hope this is helpful!**